# pkgin: /usr/pkg does not have enough space for installation (276M required only 274M available)

Tags: bsd, netbsd

I try to install `gnome-2.26.2nb5` on NetBSD-7.0 but I receive the following message:

`computer#pkgin install gnome-2.26.2nb5
pkgin: /usr/pkg does not have enough space for installation (276M required only 274M available)`

It's a fresh install of NetBSD-7.0 and I have installed it on a partition with size of around 23GB.

I wonder what is the best way to increase the size of `/usr/pkg` on NetBSD.

Output of `df -lh` is like:

```
Script started on Tue Mar  1 05:02:04 2016
dhcppc9# df -lh
Filesystem         Size       Used      Avail %Cap Mounted on
/dev/wd0a           21G        20G       274M  98% /
kernfs             1.0K       1.0K         0B 100% /kern
ptyfs              1.0K       1.0K         0B 100% /dev/pts
procfs             4.0K       4.0K         0B 100% /proc
tmpfs              384M         0B       384M   0% /var/shm
/dev/sd0e           30G       1.5G        29G   4% /mnt
dhcppc9# exit

Script done on Tue Mar  1 05:02:16 2016
```

Also `du -sh /usr/pkgsrc` shows that 15GB is consumed by `/usr/pkgsrc`. I installed NetBSD-7.0 recently and at first I tried to compile/build gnome desktop environment, but ran into an error after hours of compiling due to a bug in `xulrunner192`. Therefore, I decided to install gnome desktop binaries with `pkgin install` but the size of file system is not enough. I think possibly compiling gnome which is a huge meta package is taking too much space on file system. I'm not sure.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: @IanKemp I flagged my own question to be migrated to another forum, after I asked my question. I'm not sure how the migration process works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your existing partition layout it might be simplest to merge /usr/pkg into /usr or to exchange its usage with another partition.

Another option might be to split another larger partition to allow for a bigger /usr/pkg, or even to reinstall (if you do not have much data on the system yet).

What does a `df -lh` report?

Comment: I added `df -lh` output to my post

Comment: You should probably clear down any of the work directories for the partially built packages - either `make clean` in `/usr/pkgsrc`, or `cd /usr/pkgsrc ; rm -rf */*/work` (the latter for the impatient :)

If you are using `pkgin` to install binary packages you could just delete all of `/usr/pkgsrc` as you only need it if you are building from source.

Comment: I'm a little surprised that compiling/building gnome desktop would consume around 15GB of file system. I figured out that there has been problems like [this](https://mail-index.netbsd.org/pkgsrc-users/2015/08/19/msg022047.html) before.

Comment: When you build a package which pulls in other packages pkgsrc keeps the extracted files & build directories for all the needed packages around, while you're building... which can lead to quite a lot of space for a large meta package like gnome.